# Is D3.js a best option when we need to contrust around 200-300 customized charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, analytics

I have a huge set of data with varieties of entities and key Metrics, and trying to create a analytic based application. 
I would like to implement customized charts say of around 200-300 which helps me render all varieties of charts for all these entities.
Which is the best way to create such huge number of customized charts as a library?

Comment: @FrankS101.... Well I have tried to use few already available libraries like Fusion Charts, High Charts, but the way it renders is very minimal to customize. so I am checking if we can build using D3.js

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what kind of analytic and charts are required.You can select any [d3](https://d3js.org/) or [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). Like my application required only Bar, pie and line with Multiple Axis and was relating to stocks thus i used HighStocks.If you want to use extensive Customization and variety of charts and graphs D3 is always a good option.

Comment: The analytic may vary from entity to entity. Its not always a plain Bar or Pie. It would be heat charts, and few widgets, tree charts, charts that support hierarchical representations etc.,

Comment: Thanks!! will try this.